# Using Visual C++ 2015 toolset for building Windows/Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

How can I use visual studio 2015 compiler for compiling code, that targets to Windows/Windows Phone 8.1?
By default Windows/Windows Phone 8.1 projects use v120 or v120_wp platform toolsets. But I want to use new version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 compiler (that supports noexcept, default move assignment and move constructor, C++ 14x features, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You cant use new compilers under Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Phone 8.1 development. Visual Studio is as you stated using v120 platform toolset for 8.1. To use new compilers you need to move to universal apps for Windows 10 project.

For reference, here is a link with answer from MS employee (near bottom in comments):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/26/visual-c-tools-for-windows-10-technical-preview.aspx

> Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 apps/components are built only using VC++ 2013 toolset (even while using VS2015)

Comment: I know about universal platform.
But I think, that maybe there are some tricks and workarounds to use new version of C++ compiler.